# "Too many arguments" issue in if statement in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm working on a script in order to automate a license re-activation. Instead of doing this manually every 40 days I want the script to do it for me.

I have added licenses to licenses.txt and the script builds a variable from the first line of the licenses.txt which is uses with the command SOAPLicenseClient. If the command is successful it will then remove that line from the file. Once the licenses.txt is running low on licenses it will send a log message to log facility local0.

When the command is successful it will print:

> New license installed

and when it is trying to install a license that has already been installed previously it will print:

> License server has returned an exception. Fault code: 51092 Fault text: Error 51092, This license has already been activated on a different unit. Please contact technical support for assistance

If it receives this error it will then remove the first line of the licenses.txt file and reuse the SOAPLicenseClient command in order to try a new license.

At the end I have a catch all that will simply print the output from $results into the log facility 0.

Here is the entire script:

```
#VARIABLES
BaseReg=$(head -n1 licenses.txt)
currentlicensecount=$(wc -l < licenses.txt)
licensewarninglimit=2
nolicenses=0

if ! [ -f "/config/licenses.txt" ]
    then 
    /bin/logger -p local0.error "License reactivation failed - Licensefile is MISSING - Please add a Licensefile to /config/licenses.txt"
fi

if [ $currentlicensecount -eq $nolicenses ]
    then
        /bin/logger -p local0.error "No licenses available! - Remaining Licenses: $currentlicensecount - Please add more licenses"
    else 
    result=$(SOAPLicenseClient --basekey "$BaseReg")
        if [ $result -eq "New license installed" ]
            then
            #Removing the recently used BaseRegistration key from the licenes.txt       
            tail -n +2 licenses.txt > licenses.tmp && mv licenses.tmp licenses.txt
            newlicensecount=$(wc -l < licenses.txt)
            /bin/logger -p local0.notice "License reactivation succeded - "$result" - Remaining Licenses: $newlicensecount"
                if [ $newlicensecount -lt $licensewarninglimit ]
                    then
                    /bin/logger -p local0.warning "Current Licensecount is below warning threshold - Remaining Licenses: $newlicensecount - Please add more licenses"
                elif [ $newlicensecount -eq $nolicenses ]
                    then
                    /bin/logger -p local0.error "No licenses available! - Remaining Licenses: $newlicensecount - Please add more licenses"
                fi
        elif [ $result -eq "License server has returned an exception. Fault code: 51092 Fault text: Error 51092, This license has already been activated on a different unit. Please contact technical support for assistance" ]
            then
            #Removing the recently used BaseRegistration key from the licenes.txt       
            tail -n +2 licenses.txt > licenses.tmp && mv licenses.tmp licenses.txt
            NewBaseReg=$(head -n1 licenses.txt)
            newresult=$(SOAPLicenseClient --basekey "$NewBaseReg")
            if [ $newresult -eq "New license installed" ]
                then
                #Removing the recently used BaseRegistration key from the licenes.txt       
                    tail -n +2 licenses.txt > licenses.tmp && mv licenses.tmp licenses.txt
                    newlicensecount=$(wc -l < licenses.txt)
                    /bin/logger -p local0.notice "License reactivation succeded - "$result" - Remaining Licenses: $newlicensecount"
                        if [ $newlicensecount -lt $licensewarninglimit ]
                            then
                            /bin/logger -p local0.warning "Current Licensecount is below warning threshold - Remaining Licenses: $newlicensecount - Please add more licenses"
                        elif [ $newlicensecount -eq $nolicenses ]
                            then
                            /bin/logger -p local0.error "No licenses available! - Remaining Licenses: $newlicensecount - Please add more licenses"
                        fi
        else
        /bin/logger -p local0.error "License reactivation failed - "$result" - Remaining Licenses: $currentlicensecount"
                if [ $currentlicensecount -lt $licensewarninglimit ]
                    then
                    /bin/logger -p local0.warning "Current Licensecount is below warning threshold - Remaining Licenses: $currentlicensecount - Please add more licenses"
                elif [ $currentlicensecount -eq $nolicenses ]
                    then
                    /bin/logger -p local0.error "No licenses available! - Remaining Licenses: $currentlicensecount - Please add more licenses"
                fi

        fi
    fi
fi
```

When running the script I receive the following errors:

```
# sh ./license_reactivation.sh
./license_reactivation.sh: line 20: [: too many arguments
./license_reactivation.sh: line 33: [: too many arguments
```

The lines it is complaining about is:

```
if [ $result -eq "New license installed" ]

elif [ $result -eq "License server has returned an exception. Fault code: 51092 Fault text: Error 51092, This license has already been activated on a different unit. Please contact technical support for assistance" ]
```

From what I can tell based on searching here is that the variable $result contains too many arguments due to the fact that it contains several different words with spaces.

Using a more simple script I echo out the $results variable:

Script:

```
#VARIABLES
BaseReg=$(head -n1 licenses.txt)
currentlicensecount=$(wc -l < licenses.txt)
licensewarninglimit=2
nolicenses=0

if ! [ -f "/config/licenses.txt" ]
    then 
    /bin/logger -p local0.error "License reactivation failed - Licensefile is MISSING - Please add a Licensefile to /config/licenses.txt"
fi

if [ $currentlicensecount -eq $nolicenses ]
    then
    /bin/logger -p local0.error "No licenses available! - Remaining Licenses: $currentlicensecount - Please add more licenses"
    else 
        result=$(SOAPLicenseClient --basekey "$BaseReg")
        echo $result
fi
```

Here is the results:

```
# sh ./license_reactivation.sh
License server has returned an exception. Fault code: 51092 Fault text: Error 51092, This license has already been activated on a different unit. Please contact technical support for assistance
```

Is it possible for me to filter out strings from $results and create new variables? I tried sed, awk and grep but I'm doing something wrong.

What is the most effective way of doing this? The code may not be pretty and if you have improvements feel free to speak up.

Comment: This is a long question. Can you trim it down to the essential information? See the help page on creating a [mcve].

Comment: Also, try running your script through http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - Ran through shellcheck and it found a few issues with quotations and a few more. Corrected those but got the same issue. I believe now that it might be related to my variable printing out 3 lines whenever it receives the "already used license" error. I posted a long question in order for you guys to fully understand what I'm trying to do. Perhaps it is best to be more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a variable contains whitespace, it gets expanded inside of `[ ... ]` and the number of parameters to `[` increases:

```
three_words='a b c'
[ $three_words = 'a b c' ]
```

is actually interpreted as

```
[ a b c = 'a b c' ]
# 1 2 3 4 5
```

I used `=` here, as `-eq` is used to compare numbers, not strings.

Do you see? 5 words!

Solution? Double quote the variable:

```
[ "$three_words" = 'a b c' ]
```

Or, if in `bash` and not caring about portability to other shells, use `[[`, it needs no quoting:

```
[[ $three_words = 'a b c' ]]
```

Comment: Still having errors I'm afraid. Tried both double brackets and double quote. I'll post my reply as an answer as the comments does not give you much to add.

Comment: @Philip.J: Updating the question might also be a way.

Comment: Ahh good thinking. I will do that from now on. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Tried with the quatations and it solve the issue. But the problem remains for the expired license and I bet this is because the error is printed into three different lines.

Comment: @Philip.J: Sure, three lines aren't equal to a single one.

Comment: Actually I got it to work by writing this: elif [ "$result" = "License server has returned an exception.
   Fault code: 51092
   Fault text: Error 51092, This license has already been activated on a different unit. Please contact technical support for assistance" ] - it is not pretty but it works :D

Comment: @Philip.J: You can also use a pattern `[[ $result == 'License server has returned an exception.'* ]]`